# Another bit on abandoned questions, but specifically good ones with good answers

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, accepted-answer

Question on a rarer type of abandoned question:

Is there a way for 'Community' to take ownership of these questions so an answer can be accepted and the data can be maintained?  Is it simpler to just create a new question and drop in the useful bits and accept it?  How is this 'supposed' to be done?

Comment: Why not just upvote it?

Comment: @JorgeCastro - Thanks, at the time I asked I was unaware of jrg's answer being a possibility.  That's why I accepted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leave them, they have good answers.

Also, if a answer has a score of 1+, than the system considers it "answered".

So in short, I don't think anything needs to happen, and I'm not sure we can even do a lot.

Comment: @guntbert answer. thanks!

Comment: Are you _really_ sure it isn't +2?  That's what I've always been told...

Comment: @Seth I'll check again.